# Flutter showMenu() x axis position

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a Gridview builder that generates the following and I have a GestureDetector with onLongPress that shows the menu as such:

[image: cards]

I am able to align the menu to respective element of the gridview, for example if I long press on the green box it should show the menu below the box:

[image]

However, I am unable to set the horizontal x position.

If I set the value of the L or R, it moves the menu to most left or right, which is not what I want. I want to center the menu to the middle of the x axis of the the green box.

```
onLongPress: () {
        RenderBox box = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
        double h = double.parse(box.size.height.toString());
        Offset position =
            box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero); //this is global position
        double y = position.dy;
        double x = position.dx;
        double w = double.parse(box.size.width.toString());

        print(x);
        showMenu(
            context: context,
            position: new RelativeRect.fromLTRB(x, 0, y + h, 0),
            items: <PopupMenuEntry>[
              PopupMenuItem(
                value: 1,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.delete),
                    Text("Delete"),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ]);
      },
```

In short I would like to do something like:

[image]

```
  body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: false,
              itemCount: data.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                childAspectRatio: 10.0 / 10.0,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: CustomCard(data[index], _key),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

CustomCard

```
 return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: _storePosition,
      onLongPress: () {
      
        showMenu(
            context: context,
            position:null,
            items: <PopupMenuEntry>[
              PopupMenuItem(
                value: 1,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.delete),
                    Text("Delete"),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ]);
      },
      child: Card(
        color: d.color,
        elevation: 5,
        semanticContainer: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                d.title,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            
             
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Hey, your `position: new RelativeRect.fromLTRB(x, 0, y + h, 0),` seems not reasonable. You are setting R to be y+h. I guess you want T or B to be that

Comment: @ch271828n I have tried many different combinations but could not get the x axis to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

*This works for me, I took the `width / 2` for both the `left` and `right`, and Set the `top` as `y + h + 20` (20 to give it extra space) from `top`.*

```
                    position: new RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
                        w / 2, y + h + 20, w / 2, 0),
```

*This is the Full **Working** `Code`* on A `Container` with some `height` and `width`.

```
            GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () {
                RenderBox box = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
                double h = double.parse(box.size.height.toString());
                Offset position = box.localToGlobal(
                    Offset.zero); //this is global position
                double y = position.dy;
                double x = position.dx;
                double w = double.parse(box.size.width.toString());
                showMenu(
                    context: context,
                    position: new RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
                        w / 2, y + h + 20, w / 2, 0),
                    items: <PopupMenuEntry>[
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        value: 1,
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.delete),
                            Text("Delete"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ]);
              },
              child: new Container(
                key: key,
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 120,
                width: 300,
                child: Center(child: new Text("Tap Me")),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help. However it is not working. When I press on the right card, it is not showing on the right. I have two cards in each row.

Comment: Hey @latil68469 I think you are implementing the onLongPress on wrong widget, Please check your code carefully, Maybe there is a mistake in implementation of the code.

Comment: I have made sure it is correct and also tried your code. Could it be because of the builder? I have updated my post with the code at the end, thank you!

Comment: @latil68469 did your tried to remove expanded widgets so far ? and if that too didn't work then please paste the code for your CustomCard widget.

Comment: I need to use the expanded, as I am using the GridviewBuilder in a column.

Comment: I replaced my customcard with what you provided and I'm getting the same issue.. so I  don't think it's that

Comment: @latil68469 Yes, Problem is with the GridviewBuilder Code and Expanded Code, you can test the code on Single CustomCard Widget, and it will work for that, but to figure out that why its not working with the Expanded and Gridviewbuilder I may need your whole code for that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this helps.

```
GestureDetector(
 onLongPressStart: (details) async{
  final offset = details.globalPosition;

  showMenu(
    context: context,
    position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
      offset.dx,
      offset.dy,
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - offset.dx,
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - offset.dy,
    ),
    items: [
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text("0"),
      ),

      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text("1"),
      ),

      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text("2"),
      ),

    ]
);

},
 child: FaIcon(
   AppIcons.ellipseFa,
   size: 22,
 ),
)
```

[image]